# Best approach to JSON info to insert into a database

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I have managed to extract from an API some information but the format its in is hard for a novice programmer like me. I can save it to a file or move it to a new list etc. but what stumps me is should I not mess with the data and insert it as is, or - do I make it into a human type format and basically deconstruct it to use after?

The JSON was already difficult as it was in a nested dictionary, and the value was a list. So after trying things out I want it to actually sit in a database. I am using postgresql as the database for now and am learning python.

```
    response = requests.post(url3, headers=headers)
jsonResponse = response.json()
my_data = jsonResponse['message_response']['scanresults'][:]
store_list = []

for item in my_data:
    dev_details = {"mac":None, "user":None, "resource_name":None}
    dev_details['mac'] = item['mac_address']
    dev_details['user'] = item['agent_logged_on_users']
    dev_details['devName'] = item['resource_name']
    store_list.append(dev_details)

try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(
        user="",
        other_info="")
#   create cursor to perform db actions
    curs = connection.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO public.tbl_devices (mac, user, devName) VALUES (%(mac)s, %(user)s, %(devName)s);"
    curs.execute(sql, store_list)
    connection.commit()
finally:
    if (connection):
        curs.close()
        connection.close()
        print("Connection terminated")
```

I have ended up with a dictionary as records inside a list:
[{rec1},{rec2}..etc]

And naturally putting the info in the database it is complaining about "list indices must be integers or slices" so wanting some advice on A) the way to add this into a database table or B) use a different approach.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: So things I found annoying:
1) inserting records into postgres the column names seem to have to be lowercase, looks like a psycopg2 thing maybe?
2) I imported pandas and used a dataframe to get the records there.

Comment: 3) still need to learn more about structures, but the JSON objects are probably not helping (i.e. why store values in a list that is in itself a value of a dictionary, which is a sub-dictionary.. etc *blows the mind*)

Now I have got near to where I need to be, any ideas on forcing a string value to a new datatype i.e. "1571323246400" > date?

Answer (score 0):

Good that you ask! The answer is almost certainly that you should *not* just dump the JSON into the database as it is. That makes things easy in the beginning, but you'll pay the price when you try to query or modify the data later.

For example, if you have data like

```json
[
   { "name": "a", "keys": [1, 2, 3] },
   { "name": "b", "keys": [4, 5, 6] }
]
```

create tables

```
CREATE TABLE key_list (
   id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   name text NOT NULL,
   mytable_id BIGINT REFERENCES mytable NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE key (
   id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   value integer NOT NULL,
   key_list_id bigint REFERENCES key_kist NOT NULL
);
```

and store the values in that fashion.

Comment: Sorry - I already made a practice table in pgAdmin with rough columns trying to map it across (tbl_devices) so thats there. Are your tables, one to store the key and one to store the value? Interesting

Comment: No, it is supposed to store tje data from that JSON, and it is just an example. My answer is general, not specific to your unknowny data model. While you write the application, you still can and should change the data model - after all, it should suit the application. When you are in production, it is too late.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz. When I look at other examples out there its always a simple array or dictionary, also it rarely covers checking in the first place if its a string based data source. There are so many ways to skin the cat but I needed to ask what experienced people thought was the best steps as you never want to bodge on top of a bodge job.